# Sharing/publishing multiple Outlook calendars on intranet

Tags: exchange, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

We're a company of about 60 employees who would like to have a central location where all our employees' presence can be easily seen by the rest of the company. We use Outlook 2013 for e-mail and calendars with an Exchange server. Sharepoint might be an option.

We've seen that we can share calendars using Outlook, but it seems like it needs to be set up for each person and that each person needs to add everyone else if they want to be able to see whether they will be available on a certain date. There also seems to be a limit of 30-ish people in such a group.

The solution we currently have is a separate "whiteboard" web application, where everyone can enter when they will be unavailable. The major issue with it is that information needs to be entered in two places and thus the information is not always up to date. We do like the overview it gives of all the employees at once. (See screenshot. One row per employee, red means unavailable.)

Ideally, what we'd like to have is the same type of view as our web app, but automatically populated from everyone's Outlook/Exchange calendars. Is this possible (without coding our own solution), and how?

[image: Partial view of our whiteboard web app]

Comment: 2 Questions: Are you using Active Directory? and 2 Have you set viewing permissions for each of the 60 users?

Comment: @ECarterYoung I'm not sure, I can ask our IT admin tomorrow when I'm back at work. 2: Not yet.

Comment: Although this is for the University of Indiana, the premise is the same.  See [Option 2](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/3821).  In order to do Option 2, you must be using Active Directory on an Intranet AD domain

Comment: @ECarterYoung That seems to be the way we already know about, but which seems limited to only 30-ish calendars at a time/per group. The UI inside Outlook itself doesn't give a good overview in the same way as our web app since it takes up more space and can't accommodate everyone at once. As an example, imagine that I'd like to know how many people are out of the office on a certain day, not just whether Jane Doe is in or not.

Comment: Something else is wrong then.  According to the [Active Directory Maximum Limits - Scalability Document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx), the maximum recommended number of users in a group is 5,000 at Server 2000 and no limit with LVR enabled and > Server 2003, and the Exchange Server uses the AD to share Objects so the same limits apply.

Comment: @ECarterYoung Ah, interesting. So you mean that the calendars of 60 people should be able to be viewed in the same view? With scroll, naturally, but not needing to change that view? I haven't tested this myself so I'm just going on what my colleagues have said.

Comment: See Answer Below.

Answer (score -2):

A network is built in steps, usually using TCP/IP for the traffic.  Routers connect the traffic together.  Behind the router is a Server. In a Windows Based environment, this server usually has multiple items installed on it.

1. An Active Directory Domain
2. A Mail Server
3. An Intranet Site
4. Optional: Corporate Internet Site.

Servers are usually built in this order also, as the Active Directory controls the Permissions for all the users created in the domain.  The mail server, in this case Exchange inherits permissions from Active Directory, as does the Intranet site, in this case Sharepoint.

---

The document I linked to in my comment to you stated that the maximum limit for the number of users is 5000 for Windows Server 2000, but the fact that you're running Outlook 2013 means that you should be using at least Exchange Server 2007, meaning LVR should be enabled.  This means you should have virtually no user limit.  It may be disabled, as you only have 60 users.  Disabling it increases bandwidth used, which will slow down perceived speed.  Adding Sharepoint will only compound the problem as the increase in traffic will also increase used bandwidth.

---

In order to Share a Calendar with All Users, one of your users, ideally the person in charge of the calendar must create a Public Calander.

1. Create a [Public Folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691104.aspx) inside the domain.  All the items contained in this folder will be seen by everyone.
2. Add the Public Folder to the Public Folders list in Outlook, if it's not already there.
3. Create a [Public Calendar](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/show/how-to-create-a-public-calendar-exchange-2010).
4. If you want to use Sharepoint, have the Sharepoint Admin create a public folder like Step 1 Above, and share the Calendar on Sharepoint.  I recommend giving every sharepoint user besides the maintainer read only access to the calendar, so that only one user is in charge.

Comment: Maybe I'm being unclear, but we want *each* user's personal calendar to be viewable by every user in the company. Not the full information about what or where, only the when. And we would like to see all of the users' calendars at once. I don't see how your answer would help us achieve that, so could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The methodology of Active Directory prevents the use you want, as the user/permission model depends on the users to do the sharing(Bottom Up).  This means that the users must each individually share their calendar w/ 59 other users, meaning each user will "see" all 60.  If the permission model were top down you could do what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, then we will have to find another way to accomplish what we want. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Thats not true at all. You can establish a group with all the users in it and give the group permissions to the calendar.

Comment: @ssnobody Sounds good, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @ssnobody That's what my answer attempted to do.  While I agree that you can share a calendar with an entire group, the OP's comments state "Not the full information, about what or where, only the when..."  Even your method will expose the What or where, and the permission model is Bottom Up

Comment: I believe you can assign a group permissions (Owner,Editor,Review,etc.) just as you assign a user permissions. I think what you actually want to do is [create a group schedule](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-view-or-delete-a-group-schedule-HP001230343.aspx). You can then [view everyone's free/busy information](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/see-others-free-busy-times-HP003084952.aspx) via this calendar although I don't think it'll hide the what,where,or when of the events unless the users mark the event private.